# Why doesn't a sound file loop in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, mp3

```
<embed src="CantinaBand.mp3" autostart="true" loop="true" width="2" height="0"> </embed>
```

I have this line in my HTML file, I want the music to loop once it ends but I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you're using an old, non-standard tag. You should be using a [`<audio>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio).

```
<audio src="CantinaBand.mp3" autoplay loop></audio>
```

Comment: +1, or check out https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#audio if you need support for older browsers

Comment: /Is there a way to loop in an iframe tag itself?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

`<audio controls autoplay loop>
    <source src="CantinaBand.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>`

I hope this will work.